# Can we fill data in Adobe livecyle pdf which is embedded in PDF Using Java?

Tags: javascript, java, adobe

I have Adobe LiveCycle PDf inf webPage. It has 6 pages. Few details would be automatically picked up from Database. I have to enter few details and click Submit. With Selenium, it is not possible. Can anyone suggest me that through programming/scripting like Java/Javascript can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

**First strategy: Native LiveCycle API Use (require an access to LiveCycle infrastructure)** 
Depending on your LiveCycle version you will be able to do this.

Your PDF must have been a lifecycle pdf one, produced by lifestyle designer. 
I recommend you to test your data with the pdf and designer.

The Adobe LiveCycle Documentation for 10.1 version explain here how to achieve this: https://help.adobe.com/en_US/livecycle/10.0/ProgramLC/WS624e3cba99b79e12e69a9941333732bac8-7de6.html

```
    * This Java Quick Start uses the EJB model and contains the following JAR files 
* in the classpath: 
* 1. adobe-for data integration-client.jar 
* 2. adobe-lifecycle-client.jar 
* 3. adobe-user-manager-client.jar 
* 4. adobe-utilities.jar 
* 5. jbossall-client.jar (use a different JAR file if the LiveCycle Server is not deployed 
* on JBoss) 
* 6. jacorb.jar (use a different JAR file if the LiveCycle Server is not deployed on JBoss) 
* 7. jnp-client.jar (use a different JAR file if the LiveCycle Server is not deployed on JBoss) 

 //Create a ServiceClientFactory object 
         ServiceClientFactory myFactory = ServiceClientFactory.createInstance(connectionProps); 

        //Create a FormDataIntegrationClient object 
        FormDataIntegrationClient dataClient = new FormDataIntegrationClient(myFactory);  

        //Import XDP XML data into an XFA PDF document 
        //Reference an XFA PDF form 
        FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream("C:\\Adobe\Loan.pdf");  
        Document inputPDF = new Document(inputStream);  

        FileInputStream dataInput = new FileInputStream("C:\\Adobe\Loan_data.xml");  
        Document inputDataFile = new Document(dataInput);  

        //Import data into the form 
        Document resultPDF = dataClient.importData(inputPDF,inputDataFile); 

        //Save the PDF file 
        File resultFile = new File("C:\\Adobe\ResultLoanForm.pdf");  
        resultPDF.copyToFile(resultFile);
```

In older versions, there was an independent API to achieve this but it seems Adobe does not support it anymore.

Then with the Designer, you can insert javascript code in the pdf in order to produce logs or directly web service code.

**Second Strategy : Selenium variation using Sikuli**

You seem to be ok to script filling process with third-party tools like selenium but you're saying that selenium does not provide you access to pdf interaction.

So I suggest you use **Sikuli** http://www.sikuli.org/ 
This tool can allow you to script any of visual interaction.

Keep in mind you have to deal with pdf recognition area and screen resolution...

Comment: Related to sikuli, how it will differentiate two input which are same but only label is different

Comment: not sure what you're asking for ... if labels are differents but "static" (not different accross several pdf) sikuli allow you to get them by picture / look

Comment: Looks like that adobe deals with the PDF which is stored in local and not empddeded in webpage?? Because my case is I don't have PDF in local and it is embedded as a paet of webpage

Comment: yes. that's why i wrote earlier that way implies access to adobe infrastructure